# Is video/mp4 a supported mime type?

Tags: lightning-web-components, files

I have a lightning web component that contains a file picker.  If I pick an mp4 file then I encounter an error.  Some thing similar to `Unsupported MIME type: video/mp4`.

I'm using Spring '22 i.e. v54 and I can see that `video/*` is included in [the list of supported mime types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_js_mime.htm) so this is a bit of a surprise.

Is `video/mp4` really a supported mime type?

Comment: Which file selector are you using? One of the two built-in ones, or a custom one? What context is this in, Digital Experience, Lightning App, App Builder, etc? We need more information.

Comment: Lightning App Builder and a custom file picker.